# I can't make velocity.js function in its simplest case. What am I missing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, velocity.js

I'm trying velocity.js with a very simple script on my browser and I'm unable to make it work. Maybe someone out there can help me?

```
    <html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/julianshapiro/velocity/master/velocity.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<div class="probatorio_torio_" style="width:50px; background-color: blue; height: 50px;">&nbsp;</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert("Se hizo, la secuencia");
    var $div = $(".probatorio_torio");
    alert($div);
    $div.velocity({opacity: 0}, 1000)
    $div.velocity({width: "500px", opacity: 1}, {duration: 400, easing: "swing"}, function(){alert("completado")});
});
</script>


</body>

</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Your class is called `probatorio_torio_`, but you're looking for `probatorio_torio`.